# Cannot Call Coroutine Scope Function in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

Here is my `BaseViewModel`

```
abstract class BaseViewModel : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    private val parentJob = SupervisorJob()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        parentJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Then I have `LevelFragment` with `LevelViewModel` which is inherited `BaseViewModel`. And in `LevelViewModel` I have `fun load() = launch {}` function.

What I'm trying to do is showing multiple `LevelFragment` using `ViewPager`. So I create `PagerAdapter` and inherit `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. What the documentation said about `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is `When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment`. I'm not sure is the viewModel part of the saved state or not but when I go to the destroyed fragment and the fragment recreated I can't call `load()` function, it's not compile error or runtime crash, but when I try to put a breakpoint in the function it's not get called. I am still able to call another function that has no coroutine scope.

Also, I already try to use viewModelScope and the result still the same.

Is anyone else running into these issues too, or do you have an idea of what could be causing this?

Comment: Assuming that `ViewModel` is the Jetpack one, a more typical approach is to get rid of your own `CoroutineScope` and use the `viewModelScope` extension property. You would then call `viewModelScope.launch {}` to execute a coroutine in that scope. However, in general, it is unclear what you mean by "I go to the destroyed fragment and the fragment recreated I can't call load() function". You may want to consider extending your question to show this code as well, in addition to explaining what "can't call" means (compile error? runtime crash? something else?).

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I already updated the question.